# GregorianCalendar comparison in android, device vs emulator discrepancy

Tags: android, calendar

I need to compare two GregorianCalendar objects within an android application. I tried:

```
myCalendar.compareTo(otherCalendar)

myCalendar.getTimeInMillis() > otherCalendar.getTimeMillis()
```

In the emulator, running under ubuntu 64bit, both works fine. I tried then on a samsung galaxy s2 device with no luck. Comparison on real device is inverted, the bigger results smaller and viceversa. Printing the value on both systems with:

```
Long.toString(myCalendar.getTimeMillis())
```

I found out that a value of 1359716008000 in the emulator (I think this is the correct one) corresponds to -636369904720 in the actual device.
Any help would be really appreciated!

Comment: Please move your solution into an answer and mark it as accepted (you might need to wait a bit for that). It this case the solution is easier to spot for the others.

Comment: @WarrenFaith Done! it says I can accept in two days! is it going notify some kind of reminder?

Comment: No it doesn't, but I guess sooner or later you will see it :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just for posterity, the problem was the GregorianCalendar value itself, I assigned the value with

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE, dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss");
myCalendar.setTime(sdf.parse(myStringDate));
```

It just needed a

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE, dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss",Locale.US)
```

as said [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Locale.html#default_locale), the default locale of emulator (maybe US) was not the same of device (italian) so I think it was misparsing the day of the week in letters ("EEE")